# How to use Hibernate @NaturalId in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use `@NaturalId` with a proper implementation and have seen the following implementation example:

[How to Use Hibernate Natural IDs in Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-hibernate-natural-ids-in-spring-boot)

However, I could not understand what the difference is between just using a `findByFieldName()` method and that implementation mentioned on that page.

So, what is the difference when searching a record by `@NaturalId` using simply this:

**Approach I:**

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {  
    Optional<Product> findByCode(String code);  
}
```

And this (with tons of implementations) >>>

**Approach II:**

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @NaturalId(mutable = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
    private String code;
}
```

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface NaturalRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    // use this method when your entity has a single field annotated with @NaturalId
    Optional<T> findBySimpleNaturalId(ID naturalId);

    // use this method when your entity has more than one field annotated with @NaturalId
    Optional<T> findByNaturalId(Map<String, Object> naturalIds);        
}
```

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class NaturalRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements NaturalRepository<T, ID> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public NaturalRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation,
            EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);

        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> findBySimpleNaturalId(ID naturalId) {

        Optional<T> entity = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)
                .bySimpleNaturalId(this.getDomainClass())
                .loadOptional(naturalId);

        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> findByNaturalId(Map<String, Object> naturalIds) {

        NaturalIdLoadAccess<T> loadAccess
                = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).byNaturalId(this.getDomainClass());
        naturalIds.forEach(loadAccess::using);

        return loadAccess.loadOptional();
    }

}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = NaturalRepositoryImpl.class)
public class NaturalIdApplication {
    ...
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository<T, ID> extends NaturalRepository<Product, Long>{    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Potentially, when you are using HBN API it may take advantage of using caches (both session- and 2nd-level), moreover, since HBN has more information about it's intestines it can manage caches more reliable than `spring`'s `@Cacheable`, however, IRL I do believe HBN cache implementation is broken: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/2nd-level-cache-does-not-work-as-expected/7041/1

Comment: `spring-data-jpa` (`Optional<Product> findByCode(String code)` method) can't take advantage of `@NaturalId` because `@NaturalId` is a proprietary feature of HBN, so, if you worry about performance you need to either use HBN API (`bySimpleNaturalId`), however there is no guarantee that you will get any visible performance benefits, or use spring caching capabilities; if you don't there is no feasible reason to use `@NaturalId` at all.

Comment: HBN - Hibernate, idiomatic way is to create Composite Repositories: https://thorben-janssen.com/composite-repositories-spring-data-jpa/, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-composable-repositories, https://vladmihalcea.com/custom-spring-data-repository/